# laravel Validate Request

Tags: laravel, request, logic, request-validation

For Examle I have Request Validation

```
'images.*'            => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg|max:10240',
'images'              => 'max:5',
```

It work In Create But , in update how I can check It , for example I already uploaded 4 image And In update I must add Only One Image , How I can validate it , is there any idea

Comment: youre already validating it. Pls be a little more Specific with your Question

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the validation value dynamically? Like, fetch the image record count first then set the value for the image validation.

```
//Fetch the remaining count
$remaining_image_count = 3;
$image_count_validation = 'max:' . $remaining_image_count;

//Setting the validation value
'images.*'            => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg|max:10240',
'images'              => $image_count_validation,
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question right you want to check if theres maximum of 5 in the Database.

```
 $count = 5 -  Media::where('post_id', $post->id)->count();
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|min:20',
        'description' => 'required|min:50',
        'img' => 'array|max:'.$count,
        'img.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
    ]);
```

if that was your question. Please be more Specific